# cutting vertex, graph theory

Tags: graph-theory

I am having a trouble with an exercise (that, in fact, I saw one very similar here, if it's not the same, but I didn't understand the dialogue between the collaborators).

I have to demonstrate that any connected graph G with |V(G)|≥3 and at least 2 vertices that are not in a cycle must have a cut vertex.

My idea was to prove it by induction:  the base case is for 3 vertices, and the middle vertex will be the vertex cut. But what about N+1 vertices? How can you prove that xD? Is it a good idea to solve this problem by induction? Or exist another way?

Comment: See Menger’s Theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All non-complete graphs have a [vertex cut](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/VertexCut.html): we delete all but two non-adjacent vertices to get a disconnected graph.  So I expect it should say "cut vertex" instead.

But then I think we only need 1 vertex v that's not in a cycle.

- If v has 2+ neighbors, then v is a cut vertex, otherwise there is a path between two distinct neighbors of v which does not include v, which implies that v was originally in a cycle (contradiction).
- If v has 1 neighbor, then its neighbor is a cut vertex: since there are 3+ vertices, deleting v's neighbor disconnects v from the remaining vertices.

(And v cannot have 0 neighbors, otherwise the graph is disconnected.)

---

If the question should say "has two distinct vertices u and v for which no cycle contains both u and v", then the above proof still works unless both u and v both belong to cycles.

We take a cycle containing u which minimizes the distance to v, and connect it to v with a shortest path.  Let x be the vertex where the cycle connects to the path.

[image: A cycle containing u and a vertex x, and a path from x to v]

Then x is a cut vertex, otherwise there is a path from the cycle to the x-v path that does not go through x, which can be used to construct another cycle containing u with less distance to v, giving a contradiction.

[image: A cycle containing u which has less distance to v]

Comment: yep, is "cut vertex", sorry, already edited
now, the other thing is that, yeah, we only need 1 vertex that's not in a cycle, but the demonstration asks for at least 2 vertex that aren't in cycle. I suppose that your reasoning remains the same in that case, right? It really makes sense, but would your reasoning change if you take it into account from two vertices that are not in a cycle, and not one?

Comment: Do you think the question should say "has two vertices u and v for which no cycle contains both u and v"?  In this case, they can both belong to cycles (and are thus not cut vertices).

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones But this is not true, is it? Consider the graph isomorphic to $P_4$ with vertices $1,2,3,4$ in order along the path and add the edges between vertices 1 and 3 and between 2 and 4. Now consider vertices 1 and 4. They are not contained in the same cycle, but this graph has no cut vertices.

Comment: @Freshman'sDream: 4 vertices and 5 edges implies it's $K_4 \setminus e$; that's a Hamiltonian graph.  (There's a cycle 1-2-4-3.)  (I didn't see the duplicate target when I answered, but apparently it's a [known theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3994863/91818).)

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones thank you so very much Rebecca!!